# Can you please identify a Star Wars fanfic in which Leia gave birth to a cyborg child?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, fan-fiction

Although this fanfic was written long ago, it became popular when *The Force Awakens* was released because Kylo Ren was obviously not a cyborg. But, the author added a new foreword saying that the theory couldn't be denied because Leia could still have a secret cyborg child.

The basic premise was that Leia fell for C-3PO and they even secretly had romantic relationship (in the new foreword, the author also wrote that it was possible Han Solo left Leia because he discovered this relationship). The fanfic also used behind-the-scene pics depicting the relationship:

[image]

[image]

Can you please identify this fanfic?

Comment: Where are you likely to have read this magnum opus?

Comment: @Valorum `Magnum Opus` LOL..

Comment: @Valorum Someone shared it with me. I don't remember from where I downloaded the ebook.

Comment: Unlike Data from Trek, I seriously doubt C-3PO is fully functional...

Comment: @Loki Are you imposing your heteronormative viewpoint on this couple?

Comment: I was just implying that Data is a more advanced android compared to C-3PO, as I'm more of a Trek fan :-P

Comment: "Look honey, she has your eyes." "Oh my! Yes, I'm afraid I'll be no good around the house until the replacement optical receptors arrive."

Comment: @Loki So you are Classist as well as Heteronormative!  Just because "Data is a more advanced android compared to C-3PO" doesn't mean that C-3PO and Leia can't have a fulfilling life together and explore all possible options within Human/Cyborg relations. :-P

Comment: [Apparently this is a thing.](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6854988/1/DroidHeart)

Comment: I voted "no" on Proposition ∞